# How to have a range of absolute values (not relative ones), the $ doesn't work

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have a table of two columns, and I have to calculate the mean of the values superior to 30. If I sort values increasingly and select manually all values >30 and then I keep the address in a cell (example D17:D150) to use it in the function of the mean `=Mean(D17:D150)` I will get the right results.
But if I sort the table in another way the value changes, even though by adding `$` (`D$17:D$150` or `$D$17:$D$150`)

My question is how to have a range of absolute values, that even if I change the sorting of the table the results of the function using the range won't change.

Comment: Why are you selecting the values manually?  Can't you just use `=AVERAGEIF(D:D,">30")`

Comment: Uh this is certainly better than mine, didn't know averageif existed haha

Comment: Oh my God your are right YowE3K, thank you so much, but just curiosity could we do selection of the values of a range, and still after re-sorting we still have the values independently from their address cells

Comment: @RabahAkrour This should be possible using the [`=INDIRECT("D17:D150")` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). But `AVERAGEIF` is preferable. We should avoid using `=INDIRECT` because it is volatile.

Comment: @Peh Yeah I used the =INDIRECT function but not like you did, what is the return of =INDIRECT("D17:D150") ?? cauz it didn't work for me it says referror

Comment: If you mean that you want to have a formula that refers to `D17:D150` at first and then, after sorting, it might refer to `D27:D160` (because that is where those cells ended up), I can't think of any way to do it.

Comment: @YowE3K exactly, even with $s, it always changes after sorting

Comment: @RabahAkrour I testet it with `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:A2"))` and it worked. Indirect returns a range here.

Comment: A sort just rearranges the **contents** of the cells, not the **locations** of the cells, therefore any references to those cells continue to refer to the same location - they don't get updated to the new location of the old contents.

Comment: @Peh After sorting, the values that were in `A1:A2` originally may now be in `A10` and `A34` - the OP wants to continue to point to the same contents after the sort, so the formula will need to change to `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A10"),INDIRECT("A34"))` after the sort.

Comment: @Peh I think your wrong cauz I just tried also and the value of average changed after re sorting

Comment: @YowE3K of course you are totally right I misunderstood the question, my bad. I thought it was the other way round like it was `A10` and `A34` after sort and he wanted to keep it `A1:A2`. But it already is by default because sort only sorts the values of the cells but not the cells themself.

Comment: Thanks everyone @YowE3K and Peh